# Cannot fix error in mounting nginx config file in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx reverse-proxy and use simple default.conf. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  authorizationmicroservice:
    image: gcr.io/root-booking-245613/authorizationmicroservice:v1
    container_name: authorizationmicroservice
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "kompose.service.type=LoadBalancer"
    ports:
      - "3002:${PORT:-3002}"
    networks:
      - backend
  musicmicroservice:
    image: gcr.io/root-booking-245613/musicmicroservice:v1
    container_name: musicmicroservice
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3001:${PORT:-3001}"
    networks:
      - backend
    labels:
      - "kompose.service.type=LoadBalancer"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:${PORT:-8080}"
    volumes:
      - ./nginxProxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - authorizationmicroservice
      - musicmicroservice
    labels:
      - "kompose.service.type=LoadBalancer"
networks:
    backend:
```

Everything works fine if I do docker-compose up, but when I try to deploy it with kubernetes, I' ve got the following error log in nginx pod:

```
Warning  Failed     
34m
                   kubelet, gke-hello-cluster-default-pool-8c57f061-7hd8 

Error: failed to start container "nginx": Error response from daemon:
 OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/nginxProxy/default.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/751acda10027acdcca21d16df3be48197170c04dd3520cd7fa8aeb083b5b6bc1/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/751acda10027acdcca21d16df3be48197170c04dd3520cd7fa8aeb083b5b6bc1/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

How should i mount volumes in Kubernetes? 
This is my nginx config,it is placed in nginxProxy

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  client_max_body_size 50m;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
  proxy_connect_timeout 600;
  proxy_send_timeout 600;
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
  send_timeout 600;
  root /srv/www/static;
  location /api/authorization {
    proxy_pass http://authorizationmicroservice:3002;
  }
  location /api/music {
    proxy_pass http://musicmicroservice:3001;
  }
  location /api/playlist {
    proxy_pass http://musicmicroservice:3001;
  }
  #this where socket io will be handling the request
  location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://musicmicroservice:3001/socket.io/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Артем, show pls output of command `ls -l /home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/nginxProxy`

Comment: @Yasen it seems that i don't have this diirectory, if i just use kompose up, i've got this warning ```Volume mount on the host "/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/nginxProxy" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host```.So if i type kompose up docker-compose.yml --volumes hostPath, i have no warning, but I've got the error above. Do you know how to solve that warning without ```--volumes hostPath```?

Comment: `docker-compose` takes configs from it's working directory. You can place `default.conf` file to that dir: `/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/nginxProxy`. But I'd suggest to follow my answer and use some a bit more common way to store `nginx` config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kubernetes, typically you store configuration data like this in a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).  It looks like [Kompose won't automatically create a ConfigMap for you](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues/1060) so you need to create it by hand.

I'd suggest [converting the Docker Compose YAML file to Kubernetes YAML files](http://kompose.io/user-guide/#kubernetes)

```
kompose convert
```

The easiest thing to do here is to create a ConfigMap from your existing config file.  (For longer-term use, I'd package it into a YAML file next to the other files Kompose created.)

```
kubectl create configmap nginx --from-file=./nginxProxy/
```

In the generated `nginx-deployment.yaml` file you are looking for two things, one to make the ConfigMap available in the pod and one to mount the resulting storage into the container.

```yaml
# Inside the deployment template
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-config
      configMap:
        name: nginx # matches `kubectl create` command
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      # other standard container settings
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config # matches `volumes:` above
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Then when you run `kubectl apply -f .` to install these objects into the cluster, it will read the configuration from the in-cluster ConfigMap, and not depend on any host-specific paths (which Kompose isn't generating anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've pointed that `nginx` config located in `./nginxProxy` directory

```
 volumes:
      - ./nginxProxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

So, `k8s` is trying to find `nginx` config `default.conf` file in the directory `/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/nginxProxy`:

> `mounting \\\"/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/home/artemda4/kubernetes-engine-samples/muniverse/nginxProxy/default.conf\\\" to rootfs`

It's a current (i.e. `./`) directory for `k8s`

I'd suggest to store `nginx` config in it's default place, e.g.: `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

So, your config will look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  authorizationmicroservice:
    image: gcr.io/root-booking-245613/authorizationmicroservice:v1
    container_name: authorizationmicroservice
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "kompose.service.type=LoadBalancer"
    ports:
      - "3002:${PORT:-3002}"
    networks:
      - backend
  musicmicroservice:
    image: gcr.io/root-booking-245613/musicmicroservice:v1
    container_name: musicmicroservice
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3001:${PORT:-3001}"
    networks:
      - backend
    labels:
      - "kompose.service.type=LoadBalancer"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:${PORT:-8080}"
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - authorizationmicroservice
      - musicmicroservice
    labels:
      - "kompose.service.type=LoadBalancer"
networks:
    backend:
```